# Write out a very large data frame in r?

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame that I need to write to a file. Just making one call to write.table causes an out of memory exception (I have a lot of memory on the box). What is the best approach to writing out a very large data frame in chunks? Just a while loop and setting append=TRUE in the calls to write.table or something else?

```
write.table(df, file=paste(args[1], ".out"), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: If the data.frame is so massive, why do you write it to a text file?

Comment: I write out the data frame and then take each line in the file, parse it, and create an item in MongoDb. I suppose it is a fair point that I could try to do this all from within R but I would prefer not to. There are roughly 23 million items in the data set.

Comment: I don't know anything about MongoDb, but your workflow seems terribly ineffective. There is probably some R package that could make your life easier.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-mongodb/

Comment: The R package sqldf is awesome with databases. I've used it with sqlite but it should work with Mongo DB as well.

Comment: Writing a loop over `write.table(df[i:(i+1000)],append=TRUE)` is certainly one way, but I'd go with the crowd suggesting you pipe directly to mongodb from R.

Comment: I will give that a shot, unfortunately, I realized that the memory issue is actually caused when taking the results of the apriori function and using the as() function to convert this to a data frame.

Comment: If you have the data.frame in R already, why don't you use `rmongodb` to write it straight into MongoDB?